# Server side requests getting lost

Tags: php, laravel, networking, nginx, homestead

I've got a problem that I haven't been able to solve involving server-side requests timing out if I try to perform 5 or more requests simultaneously.

Here's a quick overview of the architecture:

- I have one server (Server-A) that hosts two websites (Web-Foo and Web-Bar).
- Web-Foo exposes a JSON API.
- Web-Bar consumes Web-Foo's API, and also exposes a JSON API that is consumed client side.

Here's a simplified workflow:

- A user visits Web-Bar, loading the page.
- When the page needs extra data, an AJAX request is made to Web-Bar that in turn creates a server-side request to Web-Foo for the data.

The above **all works** - until 5 (or more) AJAX requests are made simultaneously. At this point, things start to timeout.

From the server logs, I can tell that the requests arrive at Web-Bar, and that Web-Bar fires off all 5 server-side requests but doesn't receive a reply until exactly 5 minutes pass (the timeout). At that point, Web-Foo's logs fill up indicating that everything's been processed correctly, but Web-Bar's logs fill up with *504 Gateway Timeout errors*.

Here are all the things I've tried:

- Make 4 AJAX requests or less to Web-Bar (This works)
- Configure Web-Bar to respond directly to the AJAX requests, and not perform a server-side request to Web-Foo (This works)
- Configure AJAX requests to directly call Web-Foo, bypassing Web-Bar (This works with any amount of requests, but is not something that can be used as a solution)
- Strip down processing on Web-Bar to identify a bottleneck elsewhere - like in accessing the database (This doesn't fix the problem)
- Configure Web-Foo to make 5+ requests to Web-Bar in PHP (This works, but the requests happen synchronously)
- Move Web-Bar to another server (This works! I can initiate as many simultaneous requests as I like, and I'll always get the correct response)

I believe that the problem is caused due to two websites **on the same server** trying to perform server-side communication with each other, and that the problem is some sort of networking issue. The issue only occurs when multiple (5+) requests are initiated simultaneously. I'm stumped as to how to proceed in debugging this problem.

Both websites are built using Laravel, and Web-Bar consumes Web-Foo's API using Guzzle 6. "Server-A" generally refers to my development environment *homestead*, though I've performed the same tests on a (forge provisioned) staging environment.

I'd appreciate any suggestions to continue debugging, or tools that I can use to find out what's happening to the server-side requests, and where/if/how they're getting lost.

Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to consume Web-Foo?

Comment: Sounds to me like your system might be running out of resources, OR you're running out of workers for whatever HTTP service you're using (looks like Nginx from your tags).

Comment: Have you tried executing the requests to localhost instead of the public domain?

Comment: @scottevans93 They're all GET requests

Comment: @Kenyon I considered that... but moving Web-Bar to another server allows it to make many, many simultaneously requests to Web-Foo. I stress tested it using an app called "Throng" that simulates many connections.

Comment: @EricTucker I haven't - the server relies on domain mapping to route the request to the right application!

Comment: @MikeStivala if you moved it to another server and it worked, that definitely sounds like a configuration issue